# How to change Jquery Animation course while animating?

Tags: jquery

I have a small jquery game where turrets fire projectiles at other divs that have been animated to move across a field. My projectiles are fired to the last position the oncoming div was near so it never hits. What I need is a way to change the course of the projectile as its moving along and it will always hit the target then because its following it. By using the mothod below I can receive the current position of the projectile but I cannot modify it as its being animated.

```
$(projectile).animate({"top":Y, "left": X},{duration:500, easing: 'linear',step: function( currentLeft,currentTop ){
 checkforenemies();
},  complete: function() {
    $(projectile).remove();

}});
```

Is there a way to modify the course of the animation within the step: function?

Answer (score 1):

Some approches come to mind:
A) You can break up the animation into steps:

```
function step(){
  while ( $(projectile).length > 0 ){ // while projectile exists
    $(projectile).animate({
      "top": getTargetY()/numberOfStepsItTakesToHitIt,
      "left": getTargetX()/numberOfStepsItTakesToHitIt },
      {duration:500, easing: 'linear', complete: function() {
        $(projectile).remove();
      }
    });
    step();
  }
}
```

B) Check if the target changed position on each step and if it does, stop the animation and start a new one:

```
function step(){
  if (targetMoved && $(projectile).length > 0){
    $(projectile).stop();
    $(projectile).animate({
      "top": getTargetY()/numberOfStepsItTakesToHitIt,
      "left": getTargetX()/numberOfStepsItTakesToHitIt },
      {duration:500, easing: 'linear', step: step, complete: function() {
        $(projectile).remove();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

C) calculate the target trajectory (based on it's position and speed) and make a guess on it's future location. Than fire in that place and check for collisions.

I like that last approach best. The projectile trajectories will not bend, but it is the most complicated.

P.S.: I didn't check the code, so it probably contains some semantic (and maybe even logical) errors.